# Apache ACL based on environment variable value

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, pingfederate

I have a vendor Apache module (PingFederate) that sets environment variables based on a token it receives. I would like to control access to directories based on the value of an environment variable.

For example the module sets variables like this:
    [PF_AUTH_SUBJECT] => aaron
    [PF_AUTH_GROUPS] => CN=Application.E18.Users,OU=Internal,DC=local,CN=Application.E17.Users,OU=Internal,DC=local

I want to secure a directory so that only users in group CN=Application.E18... can access it. My location direction conf looks like this:

```
<Location /example_app>
    SetEnvIf %{PF_AUTH_GROUPS} ^.*CN=Application.E18.Users.*$ ALLOWED
    AuthName "ACL PingFederate restricted"
    AuthType PFApacheAgent
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from all
</Location>
```

This doesn't seem to work. I've tried:

```
SetEnvIf %{PF_AUTH_GROUPS} ^.*CN=Application.E18.Users.*$ ALLOWED
SetEnvIf %{PF_AUTH_GROUPS} ^.*Application.*$ ALLOWED
SetEnvIf %{PF_AUTH_GROUPS} ^.*A.*$ ALLOWED
```

The only thing that works is:

```
SetEnvIf %{PF_AUTH_GROUPS} ^.*$ ALLOWED
```

That obviously won't work.

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25725 somewhat intimates that SetEnvIf won't test environment variables but the docs at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html mentions "an environment variable in the list of those associated with the request", which this should be.

I've also tried mod_rewrite using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
<Location /example_app>
    RewriteCond  %{PF_AUTH_GROUPS}  ^.*Application.E18.Users.*$
    RewriteRule - [E=ALLOWED:1]
    AuthName "ACL PingFederate restricted"
    AuthType PFApacheAgent
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

In all of these instances the ALLOWED environment variable is not set.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to make `mod_rewrite` execute 2 times to be able to leverage the headers produced by `mod_pf`, since the latter executes after the former:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_PASS} !1
RewriteRule .* $1 [L,E=PASS:1]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:PF_AUTH_GROUPS} !^.*ECN.*$
RewriteRule .* $1 [L,R=401]
```

This is also documented here: https://ping.force.com/Support/PingIdentityArticle?id=kA340000000Gs7bCAC